# How can I get a wallet Id when cardano-wallet create return wallet_already_exists

Tags: cardano

So far when I try to create a wallet with a recovery phrase that already exist the server returns 409 conflict and an error message saying: "This operation would yield a wallet with the following id: {id} However, I already know of a wallet with this id."

So the question is: Is there another way rather than extracting the id from the response message? I mean hopefully there is a better way to get the wallet Id, from the recovery phrase maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [soccer193](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15353333/soccer193) already point out, there isn't a way to get back the wallet Id from the mnemonic phrase right now although there are plans to include it in some way as you can confirm from this [issue](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-wallet/issues/2602) from `cardano-wallet`'s github repo.

Answer (score 4):

Not at present, `POST /v2/wallets` is the only way the app allows a user to provide a mnemonic phrase, and as you've found it doesn't return the ID as a separate field.

If you're using cardano-wallet to handle only a single wallet, one could just 'List' all wallets, and pick it from the list.

Comment: how can I pick it from the list, I guess that by name right?

Comment: if you're only handling one wallet at a time, then `GET /v2/wallets` will return a JSON array with only one element in the array. So, you'd do something like `myWallet = result[0]`, if you had saved the JSON array to `result`.